# Run one file or map in phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm using laravel and I've written some test files. But how can I exec only one file? When I do for example: `phpunit tests/resulttesting/school/deleteSchoolForRealTest` It throws an error:

> Cannot open file
>   "tests/resulttesting/school/deleteSchoolForRealTest.php".

When I run phpunit it runs all my tests. And how can I exec only one folder? I'm on a mac.

Comment: Make sure you got letter casing right, it depends on your filesystem and the path might be case sensitive.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly.

**1)**

First way to add **folder**.
My correct way was:

```
phpunit tests/EWalletTest
```

I had same errors when I forget to start from "tests" folder

```
phpunit EWalletTest
```

I got

> Cannot open file "EWalletTest.php".

**2)**

**Filter** is another option. [read here](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/textui.html)
example:

```
phpunit --filter EWallet
```

> Only runs tests whose name matches the given regular expression pattern.

Meaning that you will have executed files `EWalletTest` and `EWalletFooTest` and test cases from other file with names like `test_EWallet_with_Australian_dollar.

Answer (score 15):

Use filter option

```
phpunit --filter=EWalletTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `phpunit.xml`

the `@group` option can be used on classes and methods.

class A

```
/**
 * @group active
 * */
class ArrayShiftRightTest extends TestCase
{
}
```

class B

```
/**
 * @group inactive
 * */
class BinaryGapTest extends TestCase
{    
}
```

in phpunit.xml

```
<groups>
    <include>
        <group>active</group>
    </include>
    <exclude>
        <group>inactive</group>
    </exclude>
</groups>
```

the classes that belongs to group active will be executed.